# Como hacer una Macro que realice un busqueda de una tabla en Ms Access?

Tags: base-de-datos, vba, ms-access

Tengo una **Base de Datos Access** en la cual busco usuarios registrados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando realizo una búsqueda me genera resultado, al hacer clic para ver la información no me genera ninguno de la información que agregué.

Esta es la macro que ejecuta el procedimiento de busqueda.

```
Option Compare Database
Private Sub Comando122_Click()
Lista123.Requery
End Sub
Private Sub Lista123_AfterUpdate()
 Dim rs As Object
Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "[id] = " & Str(Nz(Me![Lista123], 0))
    If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es una consulta para que te traiga la info, yo lo haria asi 
Cuando ya tienes el nombre que buscas dale doble click y en ese evento colgar la consulta para que te lleve la info a los controles

Una consulta mas o menos asi

```
obSQL = "Select * from " & DestinoFacturas & " Where " & _
  DestinoFacturas & ".FiscalNumber = '" & ValorActual & "';"
Set conAccess = New ADODB.Connection
With conAccess
  .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
  .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = MiPasswordAccess
  .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & MiRutaCAccess & ";"
  .Open
  Set Datos = conAccess.Execute(obSQL)
    If IsNull(Datos.Fields(0)) Or Datos.EOF Then
      CmbBMidato = ""
    Else
      CmbBMidato = Datos.Fields(0)
      CmbBMidatoI = Datos.Fields(0)
    End If
  .Close
End With
```